# What is _PyObject_GetAttrId() in CPython?

Tags: python, c, python-3.x, interpreter, cpython

I looked at sysmodule.c in CPython and came across this code`stdin_encoding = _PyObject_GetAttrId(fin, &PyId_encoding);`, but I couldn't find any documentation of it.

What is `_PyObject_GetAttrId()`?

https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Python/sysmodule.c#L597

Answer (score 0):

The `...Id` family of functions are internal-only CPython optimizations. Instead of allocating a `PyObject*` string for the identifier name, they have an intern pool of identifiers that they can use.

You can see in the [implementation](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2217462bda1865a047d358306088682ee6a091ed/Objects/object.c#L853) that they can pull out a lazily allocated `str` with `_PyUnicode_FromId`.